# How to pivot a large data frame (or matrix) without hitting memory limits?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of millions of rows that represent customers buying products. I need to reshape it from this long format to a wide format such that each row represents the number of times a customer bought each product.

For example, this creates a mock dataset.

```
# Create mock dataset of 1 million customers and thousands of products.
df <- data.frame(cust = 1:1e6)
products = paste0(sample(letters, 1e6, replace = T), " - ", 
                  sample(1:1000, 1e6, replace = T))
df$prod <- products
df$orders <- floor(rpois(1e6, 2))
```

When I use dplyr's `pivot_wider()`, I get a memory error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.0 Mb`

For example:

```
wide = pivot_wider(df, 
                   id_cols = cust, 
                   names_from = prod, 
                   values_from = orders
                   )
```

How can I pivot a large data frame (or matrix) without hitting memory limits?

The resulting data should look like this:

```
cust item1 item2 ...
1     0     2
2     4     0
...   ...   ...
1000000 0   1
```

- I do not NEED to use a data frame
- I do not need to use the tidyverse; base R solutions are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have having memory issues, maybe a sparse matrix will help. It may be a bit trickier to deal with, but I am sure you can get up to speed with the vignettes.

```r
library(Matrix)

customers <- unique(df$cust)
products <- unique(df$prod)

df$row <- match(df$cust, customers)
df$col <- match(df$prod, products)

df_sparse <- sparseMatrix(
  i = df$row, 
  j = df$col,
  x = df$orders,
  dimnames = list(customers,
                  products)
)

dim(df_sparse)
# [1] 1000000   26000
```

Comment: This does just what I needed. Thanks Adam! I'll upvote this as soon as I get enough reputation.